# Optimize MDX query

Tags: query-optimization, ssas, mdx

I have two needs in my query
First : to have a sorted product list base on my measure.product with higher sales should appears first.

```
ProductCode Sales                       
----------- ------------                                            
123          18     
332          17      
245          16          
656          15
```

Second : to have cumulative sum on my presorted product list.

```
ProductCode   Sales      ACC                       
----------- ------------ ----                                            
123          18          18
332          17          35
245          16          51
656          15          66
```

I wrote below MDX in order to achieve above goal:

```
WITH
 SET SortedProducts AS
     Order([DIMProduct].[ProductCode].[ProductCode].AllMEMBERS,[Measures]. [Sales],BDESC) 
 MEMBER [Measures].[ACC] AS
 Sum
    (
      Head
      (
       [SortedProducts],Rank([DIMProduct].[ProductCode].CurrentMember,[SortedProducts])      
      )
     ,[Measures].[Sales]
    ) 
SELECT  
      {[Measures].[Sales]  ,[Measures].[ACC]} 
   ON COLUMNS,
      SortedProducts
   ON ROWS 
 FROM [Model]
```

But it takes about 3 minutes to run,any suggestion on how to optimize my code or is it normal?

> I have 9635 products in total

Answer (score 0):

if you do a quick research on google, there are different ways to achieve it (many answers here as well).

That said, I will give a try to this different way to calculate your running total

```
MEMBER [Measures].[SortedRank] AS Rank([Product].[Product].CurrentMember, [SortedProducts]) 
MEMBER [Measures].[ACC2] AS SUM(TopCount([SortedProducts], [Measures].[SortedRank]) ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
```

I don't know if `TopCount` will perform faster than `Head` for your case, but for example your query on my test machine on AdventureWorks cube takes the same time using Head or TopCount function.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is as fast as my own query .